# Get all selected table rows onclick of a submit button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one table populated from csv file. user will upload and can select a particular row. On click of submit button all the selected row data will be sent to a webservice.

I have done everything like populating the data and all using AngularJS(v1.6) and also i can get particular rowData onclick of a checkbox. But the problem is .checked is giving false if am not selecting all the rows. As a result if user checks and again uncheck a particular row then that value am not able to remove.

heres my code:

```js
$scope.getRow = function(n,item){
        var selectedRows = [];
        console.log(item);
        console.log(document.getElementById("checkboxValue").checked);
        //will push all selected items to selectedRows
    }
```

```html
<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th ng-repeat="(key,data) in tableData[0]">{{key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in tableData">
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxValue" ng-          click="getRow(this,item)" /> </td>
        <td ng-repeat="(key,data) in item"> {{data}}</td>
     </tr>
</table>

<button ng-click="executeQuery()">Execute</button>
```

table will look like 
[image]

Comment: Please correct your source code. it shows ref error while run.

Comment: You can try attaching a click event to checkbox so that you on it clicks you can check it's checked or not & depending on that you can add or remove data from the main collection.

Comment: @RonitMukherjee exactly thats what am doing. But the problem is if you are not selecting all the checkboxes it'll give you false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add ng-model to your checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"/>
```

and instead of updating(adding/removing items from) selectedRows everytime user clicks a checkbox, you can add checked values to selectedRows when user clicks on submit function by iterating through tableData.

```
var selectedRows = [];

angular.forEach($scope.tableData, function(value, key) {
    if(value.checked){
        selectedRows.push(value);
    }
});
```